# What can I do to make this table extend further?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

https://joylandcreative.com/barchpadness-notworking-2/

Need the full table to be visible, but it can only be as long as the .w3-bar, which i can't seem to change the width of.

````
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>
    <div class="w3-bar">
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Leaderboard')">Leaderboard</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Bracket')">Bracket</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Tracker')">Tracker</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="openCity('Upsets')">Upsets</button>

</div>

<div id="Leaderboard" class="w3-container city">
 <iframe style="width:90%;height:400px;margin:auto;" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR2Y8iROpujT5OdXpQgwl-eSywABSce4eMsWuJYZht1gqfBHTijjFSzEj24dxYf1cYM5dKPSIB7KIrg/pubhtml?gid=178422594&single=true&widget=false&headers=false&chrome=false"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="Bracket" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <iframe style="width:1114px;height:782px;" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR2Y8iROpujT5OdXpQgwl-eSywABSce4eMsWuJYZht1gqfBHTijjFSzEj24dxYf1cYM5dKPSIB7KIrg/pubhtml?gid=15189697&range=B4:S70&single=true&widget=false&headers=false&chrome=false"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="Tracker" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
<iframe style="width:1088px;height:605px;" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR2Y8iROpujT5OdXpQgwl-eSywABSce4eMsWuJYZht1gqfBHTijjFSzEj24dxYf1cYM5dKPSIB7KIrg/pubhtml?gid=293817679&single=true&widget=false&headers=false&chrome=false"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="Upsets" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
    <iframe style="width:1046px;height:705px;" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR2Y8iROpujT5OdXpQgwl-eSywABSce4eMsWuJYZht1gqfBHTijjFSzEj24dxYf1cYM5dKPSIB7KIrg/pubhtml?gid=237690339&single=true&widget=false&headers=false&chrome=false"></iframe>
    </div>
<script>
function openCity(cityName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

in code

```
<div id="primary" class="col-md-8 mb-xs-24 no-sidebar">
```

change class col-md-12[image]

Answer (score 0):

This css is causing the table to not be the same width as .w3-bar:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}
```

> This is defined in `bootstrap.css:1943`